# sum over date range in report (not query)

Tags: report, ms-access-2010

In Access 2010, I have a little form prior to a report which asks the user for a date range (e.g. 7.7.2015 - 9.9.2015). I pass this date range to the report as filter. The query contains the fields ActDate, Activity and Hours. I now want the report to look like:

```
Activities from <startDate> to <endDate>:

Activity       Total Hours
Reading        5
Writing        8
Talking        3
```

What I'm getting is

```
Activities from <startDate> to <endDate>:

Activity       Total Hours
Reading        2
Reading        3

Writing        1
Writing        3
Writing        4

Talking        1
Talking        2
```

The report should sum up equal activities over the selected date range and not display a separate line for each activity which just occured on a different date. Adding a group in the report for activities is no solution (it just adds extra blank lines).

I guess it's possible to build a custom query after the user dialog (in the query I could filter by date range and GROUP BY Activity), but it would be much simpler if the grouping could be done in the report without changing the query. Do I really have to change the query?